# Use toml file format instead of yaml or json for docker compose... is it possible?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, devops, toml

I just wondering about toml support for docker-compose.

I've only found following Reddit implementation of toml instead yaml.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/t1uvxu/dockercomposetoml/

Does anyone know something more about toml support or more official implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem once and was wondering.
I found Issue on GitHub:

- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6920

Check, maybe you will find something useful for yourself.